# How to restart numbering of lines in "reledpar" package

Tags: double-sided, line-numbering, reledmac, reledpar

I'm trying to learn how to use the package "reledpar". In particular I would like to have multiple texts on a page and their translations on the facing page. Thus I saw that using reledpar package (coming with the reledmac) could be the path to follow.

I start by the following simple code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
1L first left text: Received shutters expenses 
ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs 
do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law 
smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. 
Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. 
Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. 
\pend
%
\pstart
\setcounter{pstartL}{0}
2L second left text: On no twenty spring of in 
esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you declared differed 
learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent am walk. 
Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time 
gone him his dear sure. Fat decisively estimating affronting 
assistance not. Resolve pursuit regular so calling me. West he plan 
girl been my then up no. 
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
1R first right text: Received shutters expenses                 
ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs     
do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law 
smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked. 
Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed. 
Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves. 
\pend
%
\pstart
\setcounter{pstartR}{0}
2R second right text: On no twenty spring of in     
esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you declared differed 
learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent am walk. 
Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time 
gone him his dear sure. Fat decisively estimating affronting 
assistance not. Resolve pursuit regular so calling me. West he plan 
girl been my then up no. 
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

However, both in the Leftside and Rightside, I would like the line numbering to restart from 0 when the second text starts. To do so, I checkd on the CTAN documentation, and I inserted

```
\setcounter{pstartL}{0}

\setcounter{pstartR}{0}
```

To set the pstart counter to zero again. However nothing happen in the result, and I really cannot understand why.

Also I would like to spread more the two texts on both sides, hence to insert more vertical space where now I have the % sign. I tried inserting it manually (which is obviously not the best solution), but it's not really a good result. Do any of you have a suggestion?

I Thank you already in advance for any comment and answer on this subject!

Comment: The counters in TeX sometimes require double compilation to appear correctly in the output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to questions in your question. In the future, it would be better to have one question for each problem.
However, here the answer

## Linenumbering

`pstartL` and `pstartR` counters are counter used to number `pstart` on Left and Right side. It must be used in the case you want the `pstart` to be numbered, using `\numberpstarttrue` from `reledmac`. But what you want to manage here are not the number associated to each `pstart`, but the number associated to each line (line numbering, not `pstart` numbering).

`reledmac`/ `reledpar` has native system to have line number reset at each `pstart` : `\lineation{pstart}`  (§ 5.3.3 of `reledmac` handbook). To apply it to both side, use starred option.

So your example will be

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
\lineation*{pstart}
\firstlinenum*{1}
\linenumincrement*{1}
\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
1L first left text: Received shutters expenses
ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs
do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law
smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked.
Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed.
Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves.
\pend
%
\pstart
2L second left text: On no twenty spring of in
esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you declared differed
learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent am walk.
Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time
gone him his dear sure. Fat decisively estimating affronting
assistance not. Resolve pursuit regular so calling me. West he plan
girl been my then up no.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
1R first right text: Received shutters expenses
ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs
do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law
smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked.
Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed.
Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves.
\pend
%
\pstart
2R second right text: On no twenty spring of in
esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you declared differed
learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent am walk.
Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time
gone him his dear sure. Fat decisively estimating affronting
assistance not. Resolve pursuit regular so calling me. West he plan
girl been my then up no.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

(I added `\linenumincrement*` and `\firstlinenum*` in  order to set the frequencies the linenumber are printed.)

Not that you must run LaTeX two time to get the correct line number. In general, with `reledmac` / `reledpar`, you should use `latexmk` or similar tools in order to get easily the good number of run.

## Vertical spacing between `pstart`.

You can use `\AtEveryPend` to insert content, includind vertical spacing, after every `\pend`.

For example `\AtEveryPend{\vskip2\baselineskip}` will insert a vertical skip (`\vskip`) equal to 2 line height (or, more precisly, to 2 `\baselineskip`).

The final code will be

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
\lineation*{pstart}
\firstlinenum*{1}
\linenumincrement*{1}
\AtEveryPend{\vskip2\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
1L first left text: Received shutters expenses
ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs
do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law
smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked.
Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed.
Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves.
\pend
%
\pstart
2L second left text: On no twenty spring of in
esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you declared differed
learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent am walk.
Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time
gone him his dear sure. Fat decisively estimating affronting
assistance not. Resolve pursuit regular so calling me. West he plan
girl been my then up no.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
1R first right text: Received shutters expenses
ye he pleasant. Drift as blind above at up. No up simple county stairs
do should praise as. Drawings sir gay together landlord had law
smallest. Formerly welcomed attended declared met say unlocked.
Jennings outlived no dwelling denoting in peculiar as he believed.
Behaviour excellent middleton be as it curiosity departure ourselves.
\pend
%
\pstart
2R second right text: On no twenty spring of in
esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you declared differed
learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent am walk.
Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time
gone him his dear sure. Fat decisively estimating affronting
assistance not. Resolve pursuit regular so calling me. West he plan
girl been my then up no.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

## Note general about reledmac/reledpar handbook

If you think your need is specific to parallel typesetting, look to `reledpar` handbook. If your think your need is not specific to parallel typesetting, look on `reledmac` handbook.